# Columns in different order

Tags: javascript, css, multiple-columns

I'm trying to recreate a type of gallery layout using the CSS "columns" property.

But I encountered 2 issues:

- columns don't fill the container and I always get n-1 columns for some reason
- order is 1-4-7, 2-5-8, 3-6-9 and I want it 1-2-3, 4-5-6, 7-8-9

For the 2nd problem I think I can reorder the elements in the HTML code with javascript, but how do I determine which have to be moved and where?

Any ideas?

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;    
}

columns{
    display: block;
    -webkit-columns: 4;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: blue;        
}

div{
    background: pink;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#d5{
    height: 43px;
}
```

```html
<columns>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div id="d5">5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
</columns>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Works only if the elements have the same height**
*which is **not** the case as OP points out.*

You don't need to use -webkit-columns for this. You can do something like

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

columns {
    display: block;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: blue;
}
    /* clear fix */
    columns:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
    }

/* the float takes care of collapsing white space between elements 
    132 = (400 - 2 x 2 [margins]) / 3 [columns] 
*/
div {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    background: pink;
    width: 132px;
    margin-right: 2px;
}
    /* we don't need right margins for the last column */
    div:nth-of-type(3n) {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
```

and no JavaScript needed either!

```css
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    columns {
      display: block;
      width: 400px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      background: blue;
    }
    /* clear fix */
    columns:after {
      content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;
    }
    /* the float takes care of collapsing white space between elements 
        132 = (400 - 2 x 2 [margins]) / 3 [columns] 
    */
    div {
      float: left;
      display: block;
      background: pink;
      width: 132px;
      margin-right: 2px;
    }
    /* we don't need right margins for the last column */
    div:nth-of-type(3n) {
      margin-right: 0;
    }
```

```html
<columns>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
</columns>
```

Comment: it only works if all the elements have the same height. i wouldn't have thought of using columns if that was the case

Comment: ah ok! I assumed it being a gallery that all the pictures would be similarly sized. obviously I wasn't thinking straight :-)

Comment: @xpedobearx - but why is the order important then? because if you are going to number them horizontally, you would be in a bit of a spot of the 2nd column images are all tall, won't you?

Comment: @xpedobearx - thinking about this a bit more, considered something like - http://packery.metafizzy.co/?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define width in %

```
columns{
width:25%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the order you get is correct...
The column are rendered vertically and when it reaches 4 then 4 is moved on side...

```
1   4   7
2   5   8
3   6   9
```

The column you are missing is empty... if you write 10div you'll see.

Try here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_columns

You have 9 elements... 9 to place in a 4columns table... but since it is filled top to right the last column of the grid id empty.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is as Sharma says, you have to define a width.

Anyway I would strongly recommend trying to play around with the Flexbox layout. It is perfect for these kind of scenarios. With Felxbox you can change the rotation of your elements with one simple declaration. Try to use column instead of row in flex-flow and you will see what I mean. (Prolly need some more alterations to make it similar to your first example)

I have done done little snippet only I have used flexbox instead of block.

```
columns{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: blue;        
}

div{
  width: 200px;
  background: pink;
}
```

It can play with it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4oo0ocvt/).

Comment: yes but that will only work if all the elements have the same height...\

Comment: The column view will depend on height yes. You could set the baseline and they would center around that. The row view will not be affected much unless you define a height of the parent container. It all depends on what your needs are. Try [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNZqEK). I prefer codepen for problems like this.